# using scope_Identity to get id to store in session variable

Tags: asp.net, sql, scope-identity

I need some help with my code. How can I get the scope_Identiy to store the ImageId as a session variable. I have been stuck on this for ages but I just cant get it to work.

edit: I believe that from the line SqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(); down is wrong. I just dont know how to fix it. Im still new to this.

```
protected void btnAddImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    //store items in session variables
    Session["AnimalName"] = AnimalNameTextBox.Text;          
    Session["TypeOfAnimal"] = TypeofAnimalDDL.Text;
    Session["Breed"] = BreedTextBox.Text;   
    Session["CrossBreed"] = CrossBreedAddDDL.Text;
    Session["Sex"] = SexDDL.Text;
    Session["Size"] = SizeDDL.Text;
    Session["Age"] = AgeDDL.Text;
    Session["Location"] = LocationAddDDL.Text;
    Session["Date"] = DateTextBox.Text;
    Session["Contact"] = ContactTextBox.Text;
    Session["Children"] = ChildrenDDL.Text;
    Session["OtherCats"] = OtherCatsDDL.Text;
    Session["OtherDogs"] = OtherDogsDDL.Text;
    Session["Neutered"] = NeuteredDDL.Text;
    Session["Microchipped"] = MicrochippedDDL.Text;
    Session["Colour"] = ColourTextBox.Text;
    Session["IndoorOutdoor"] = IndoorOutdoorDDL.Text;
    Session["Details"] = DetailsTextBox.Text;




      string s_Image_Name = txt_Image_Name.Text.ToString();
    if (FileUpload1.PostedFile != null && FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName != "")
    {
        int newImageID ;
        byte[] n_Image_Size = new byte[FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength];
        HttpPostedFile Posted_Image = FileUpload1.PostedFile;
        Posted_Image.InputStream.Read(n_Image_Size, 0, (int)FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength);

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RescueAnimalsIrelandConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Images(Name,[Content],Size,Type) VALUES (@Image_Name,@Image_Content,@Image_Size,@Image_Type); SELECT ImageID = SCOPE_IDENTITY ()";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = conn;


        SqlParameter Image_Name = new SqlParameter("@Image_Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 500);
        Image_Name.Value = txt_Image_Name.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(Image_Name);

        SqlParameter Image_Content = new SqlParameter("@Image_Content", SqlDbType.Image, n_Image_Size.Length);
        Image_Content.Value = n_Image_Size;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(Image_Content);

        SqlParameter Image_Size = new SqlParameter("@Image_Size", SqlDbType.BigInt, 99999);
        Image_Size.Value = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(Image_Size);

        SqlParameter Image_Type = new SqlParameter("@Image_Type", SqlDbType.VarChar, 500);
        Image_Type.Value = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(Image_Type);


        SqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (dataReader.HasRows)
        {
            dataReader.Read();
            newImageID = Convert.ToInt32(dataReader["ImageID"]);
        }

        dataReader.Close();

        }
```

Comment: Doesn't address the problem, but you can use `ExecuteScalar` instead of using a DataReader

Comment: What exactly is the error/exception message that you are getting? And is `newImageID` a class field?

Comment: @bala no error its just not working. I have been working on it for ages and have it saving the image but no idea how to get it to give me the id of the saved row. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Two suggestions:

First, do this in a stored procedure if possible. Return your new id as an output parameter

Second (and this may require some experimentation and spell checking - I haven't tried it), add an output parameter to your command and change the comamnd text slightly to get the value

```
SqlParameter Image_ID = new SqlParameter("@Image_ID", SqlDbType.Int);  
Image_ID.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
cmd.Parameters.Add(Image_ID);
```

Change command text: `SELECT @Image_ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()`

To read the result: `int newId = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@Image_ID"].Value)`

Comment: thanks. cant get it to work. but think its my parts of the code and not this.

Comment: thanks, my new error is An SqlParameter with ParameterName 'Image_ID' is not contained by this SqlParameterCollection. I really have no idea what I have wrong..

Comment: typo - use "@Image_ID" - answer fixed

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Session["newImageID"] = Convert.ToInt32(dataReader["ImageID"]);
```

and when you want to retrieve newImageId, use

```
int newImageID = Session["newImageID"] as Int32;
```

Comment: im trying that now. im getting the error ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed. What am I missing to open the connection?